# Mongoose return document if a search string is in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is a snapshot of my model schema...

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

let postSchema = Schema({
    title: { type: String, unique: true },
    uri: { type: String, unique: true },
    image_uri: { type: String },
    content: {
        mrkdwn: { type: String },
        html: { type: String }
    }, 
    excerpt: { type: String },
    tags: [{ type: String }], // This is an array of tags,
                              // I want to find all documents whose tags
                              // array contains a search string
    creator: { type: String, default: 'some name' },
    category: { type: String },
    type: { type: String, default: 'Standard' },
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    latest_timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Here is a snapshot of a query...

```
var queryParams = {
     category: 'someCategory',
     tags: ['someTag']
   }

Post.find(queryParams).exec((err, posts) => {
        // Do some stuff in here
    }
```

I want to return all results whose `tags` field contains some `'search string'` but it isnt working for me at the moment.  How should I go about obtaining this functionality?

### Edit - Addtional Info

some records may have a tag array of `['cool', 'lame']` and another has `['cool']` but only the latter is returned with the following `queryParams` object.

```
var queryParams = {
         tags: ['cool']
       }
```

### Solution - Thanks to @Veeram

The following query will match any document whose tags array matches any value in the search array.

```
var queryParams = { tags: { $in: ['cool'] } }
```

Comment: Your query looks good. Verify your inputs (value and type) and make sure it matches to the document you are expecting to return.

Comment: the query is good even though the `tags` field is an array.  I want to return all documents so long as some string is contained within the documents returned `tags` array

Comment: You have the right query for array. It should just work the way you are describing. What happens when you run the query on your data ? Does it work without any filter ?

Comment: Are you receiving err in exec or simply posts is empty array?

Comment: I am getting results, check my edit to the post

Comment: does the `'cool'` in the tags query need to be wrapped in an array???

Comment: Not really. It should match both documents. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#array-element-equals-a-value

Comment: hmmmmm, do you think the problem lies in Mongoose?

Comment: You can add `mongoose.set('debug', true);` at the top of the file to see what query mongoose is issuing.

Comment: Ok, I think i see the problem, the actual query was this `queryParams.tags = ['cool']` vs the desired `queryParams.tags = 'cool'`

Comment: This being said, how would you go about trying to match any one of multiple selectors? eg `queryParams.tags = ['cool','lame'];`

Comment: Use `$in`. Something like `{tags: {$in:['cool','lame']}}`;

Comment: that is what i was looking for, thank you!